# Question about controlling servos with PWM while being able to accurately read the current from a sensor

Tags: sensors, servo, arduino-leonardo, current, atmega32u4

Hi I am hoping to design a custom board ATMEGA32u4 with practically a Arduino leonardo bootloader. I plan to control up to 12 servos while being able to read back the current sensor voltage of an INA169 current sensor on voltage changes. The  voltage reading will be read back into a digital pin through an ADC controlled by a  multiplexer. The question is am I able to manage all the current sensing on all 12 servos properly with this setup? or should I use a faster controller that act as a master to do the data collection from the current sensor while the ATMEGA32u4 focus on controlling the servos? I plan to store this data too, so is this the right way of doing things?

Comment: a digital output would be better, like the ina219. expect some noise, but it should still be able to give you a rough idea or identify stuck motors.

Comment: @dandavis I think previously was using the INA219 for current sensing but can't remember why my partner and me instead choose the 169 over the 219(i think we plan to have an current sensor each on the high side of every servo and wasn't sure if the I2C protocol was fast enough or if there were enough addresses to control 12 of them.). I think the purpose was to use the current sensor to have better control of those cheap micro servos 9g by reading back it current draw and potentiometer reading.